# Numpy: Referencing an array column in another array without copies

Tags: pointers, numpy, optimization

Using numpy, say you have a 3D array called *img* filled with pixel values and you want to build an array filled with zeros everywhere but on a given color channel. For example say that `img[0,0]=(42,84,126)` in the output array dedicated to the red channel I'd like to have `output_red[0,0]=(42,0,0)`.

This can be trivially done like this for example:

```
output_red=np.zeros(img.shape,dtype=img.dtype)
output_red[...,0]=img[...,0]
```

However  I'm still trying to figure out if there is a way to do it:

1. without changing anything in *img* (otherwise I won't be able to extract the other color channels)
2. without copying data from *img* to *output* at some point.

This can be trivially done in C using pointers but as numpy.ndarrays must be continuous in memory there is IMHO no hope to do so with array slicing. Array masks are not working either as their filled() method copies the data and I have to admit I have no other idea.

Do you know some magic trick in numpy to do this or is it hopeless ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is phrased, the answer is no.

(If you explain more about your goal and how you'd eventually use the output array, we might be able to suggest alternative solutions, e.g. that the output array doesn't have to be an array at all, or that it doesn't have to have the same shape as the input.)

Numpy ndarrays which *own* their data hold a structure which is continuous in memory, and is not shared with other arrays which *own* their data. The way to "share" is using views (i.e. arrays which *don't own* their data) (e.g. when slicing), but a view refers to a single other array, it cannot refer to segments of multiple ndarrays.

Depending on your use case, it might be acceptable to create a bigger ndarray containing all the additional zeros, and then slice it to get the "color" views you want.

Something like:

```
arr = np.array(..., shape = (N,M,3*3))
real_colors_arr = arr[..., :3]  # all the rest are zeros
red_arr   = arr[..., 0::3]
green_arr = arr[..., 1::3]
blue_arr  = arr[..., 2::3]
```

Comment: Actually your idea does exactly what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: `arr` is 3x larger than `img`; where does it get its data from?

Comment: @hpaulj it contains all the NxMx3 values of the original array, concatenated with NxMx6 zeros

Answer (score 1):

@shx2 answer was the right one, for posterity here is how I did it if anybody else has this problem one day:

```
# allocate a new array to store the image data and
# get a view on each channel without copies
# - width and height are the same as frame
# - contains 9 entries for each pixel
# - each entry organized like that: blue 0 0 0 green 0 0 0 red

frame_container=np.zeros((h, w, depth*3), dtype=np.uint8)
frame=frame_container[...,::4]


#get a view on each channel as (b,0,0), (0,g,0), (0,0,r)
channels={"blue":frame_container[...,:3],
                "green":frame_container[...,3:6],
                "red":frame_container[...,6:]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't *explicitly* copy nor do in-situ changes as mentioned in the two requirements, but will use altogether new *placeholder* for the output -

```
output_red = np.einsum('ijk,k->ijk',img,np.array([1,0,0]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [56]: img
Out[56]: 
array([[[ 50,  83, 185],
        [ 83, 116, 125],
        [ 43, 179,  11]],

       [[108, 160, 122],
        [ 55, 206,  96],
        [134, 149, 232]]])

In [57]: np.einsum('ijk,k->ijk',img,np.array([1,0,0]))
Out[57]: 
array([[[ 50,   0,   0],
        [ 83,   0,   0],
        [ 43,   0,   0]],

       [[108,   0,   0],
        [ 55,   0,   0],
        [134,   0,   0]]])
```